# API to access open file handles in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Is there a way to find out number of open file handles for a HDFS file? I went through the documentation, could not find anything useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Note : I am using hadoop 1.0.4

Comment: What is an open file handle in HDFS in your opinion? When someone reads from the file? Who should keep track of such a thing over thousands of nodes?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to identify whether someone is reading the file. I tried to use the access time, it gives 99% accuracy. I get your point. Namenode may not be tracking the file reads.